# How to ask for re-open after edit with low rep?

Tags: support

On other sites I was able to edit a question and then ask for re-open. I'm not seeing the option.

I've edited the following question and I feel others may be wondering the same thing: [Do I need ubuntu-desktop if I'm using i3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837954/do-i-need-ubuntu-desktop-if-im-using-i3)

*Edit: question now re-opened, thanks Ubuntu people!*

Answer (score 7):

Since the post has been closed for more than five days, editing will not automatically send it to the reopen queue. If you don't have the privilege to vote to reopen, the best thing to do in my opinion is make a meta post (check!) or you could come into the main chatroom and raise the issue.

[The help center has some further advice](https://askubuntu.com/help/reopen-questions)

I've voted to reopen the question, so it's in the review queue now.

Comment: Alternative is mod flags if the person doesn't have meta or chat rep yet, which isn't the case here (just saying for the masses :P)